# Получить общий экземпляр IdentityUser авторизованного пользователя для текущего запроса

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

В моем ASP NET Core приложении, при обработке одного запроса, может возникнуть ситуация, когда сразу в нескольких местах требуется объект ApplicationUser (наследник IdentityUser), который инкапсулирует свойства нашего авторизованного пользователя.

Код контроллера:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User); //_userManager - объект UserManager<ApplicationUser> - AspNet Identity
manageruser.NavProperty.Load(); //что-нибудь делаем с ним
...
```

Далее, ViewComponent. Там мы будем считать число непрочитанных сообщений:

```
public async Task<string> InvokeAsync()
{
      var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
      int messages = user.GetUnreadMessages();
      ...
}
```

Собственно, меня смущает тот факт, что мы для одного запроса несколько раз обращаемся к бд, чтобы получить один и тот же объект.

Где можно его получить один раз, чтобы он был доступен из любой точки приложения? В ViewData - так это в каждый метод контроллера пришлось бы. В Startup через DI тоже не получится - конструктор его будет вызван до установления зависимостей.

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь воспользоваться кешированием, *InMemory* или *Redis*, например, если не хочешь лезть в базу каждый раз.

Можешь, например, в *MiddleWare* его закешировать.